# Query related to job queuing in Spring batch admin project

Tags: spring-batch, job-scheduling

I am working on a project based on spring batch admin. I use spring-integration's 
  `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter/>`
which picks the message from the queue and pushes them into a channel which invokes the service activator. the service activator then invokes the batch job.

spring-batch-admin internally uses a taskExecutor with pool size as 6(available in spring-batch-admin-manager-1.2.2-release.jar). This task executor has a `rejectionPolicy` configured as `ABORT` i.e. if the request for jobs are more than 6, abort other job requests. But when i run the project with over 100 requests, i see them with status as STARTING in the spring batch admin console although, only 6 job requests at a time gets processed.

I am not understanding where are the remaining job requests getting queued. Would appreciate if someone could explain me this or give some pointers.

Configurations:

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" 
    connection-factory="connectionFactory"  
    destination-name="${JMS.SERVER.QUEUE}" channel="jmsInChannel"  
    extract-payload="false" send-timeout="20000"/>
<integration:service-activator id="serviceAct" input-channel="jmsInChannel" output-channel="fileNamesChannel" 
                                ref="handler" method="process" />   

<bean id="handler" class="com.mycompany.integration.AnalysisMessageProcessor">
    <property name="jobHashTable" ref="jobsMapping" />
</bean> 
 <batch:job id="fullRebalanceJob" incrementer="jobIdIncrementer">
    <batch:step id="stepGeneral">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <bean class="com.mycompany.batch.tasklet.DoGeneralTasklet" scope="step">
                <property name="resultId" value="#{jobParameters[resultId]}" />
            </bean>
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:next on="REC-SELLS" to="stepRecordSells"/>

        <batch:fail on="FAILED" />
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="stepListener" />
        </batch:listeners>          
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="stepDoNext">
        <batch:tasklet ref="dcnNext" />

    </batch:step>
   </batch:job>
```

Thanks in advance. Let me know if more details are required.